# Running spring boot tests parallelly using gradle create two application contexts

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

We have 2 spring boot integration tests runnig on Netty.

We use gradle to run tests parallelly using flag: `org.gradle.parallel=true`

Test 1: `@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)` creates `org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.AnnotationConfigReactiveWebServerApplicationContext@3736a122`

Test 2: `@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.MOCK)` creates `org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.GenericReactiveWebApplicationContext@45fa13a7`

Two application contexts are created and one of the application contexts randomly is injected to production code and as a result we have two sets of beans.

The following dependencies are used:

dependencySet(group: 'org.springframework', version: '5.3.5')

dependencySet(group: 'org.springframework.boot', version: '2.4.4')

Is is ok behaviour, because in one case: mock web environment is used and in another real web environment?

Comment: As expected as they have 2 different configs, thus 2 instances . If you are using a classic singleton to hold your `ApplicationContext` you will run into issues. While the tests run in parallel they run in the same JVM and thus only 1 value for the static field can exist and basically the last one started will win. To fix don't use a class like that.

Comment: We don't have any static fields or do you mean singelton injection? And when we change mock to webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT one application context is created and used everywhere.

Comment: Correct as it is the same config. No I mean static fields. But I suspect you have something like an `ApplicationContextHolder` in your code. At least judging from your description, else your question/problem isn't clear. Is it correct that there are 2 contexts created yes it.

Comment: @Inject
  private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

Comment: I still don't get your question. Is this a problem? Isn't it? Is your question about the 2 contexts? Or... So again yes you have 2 contexts, and thus 2 sets of all your beans, that is to be expected.

Comment: If every @SpringBootTest creates its own application context and there are 1000 of such tests, so 1000 application contexts will be created, if we run tests parallelly?

Comment: No. Only tests that differ in configuration, for each unique set of configs there is 1 context. In this case there is a difference in the runtime (real and mock) and thus different contexts. I suggest you read the Spring test section on how context caching works.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks I will read how cache works.

Comment: There is a whole section in [the Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management-caching) about this.

Comment: After debugging, reading logs and docs we have found how cache works. You can answer to this question regarding cache and I will accept it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When utilizing the Spring Test Context Framework it will do [context caching](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management-caching). When the same context configuration is used it will re-use an existing context (or start one if not already there). If there is a new configuration combination (in your case there is a difference in the runtime i.e. start a real server or use a mock environment) it will start a new one.

From the aforementioned reference guide:

> An `ApplicationContext` can be uniquely identified by the combination of configuration parameters that are used to load it. Consequently, the unique combination of configuration parameters is used to generate a key under which the context is cached. The TestContext framework uses the following configuration parameters to build the context cache key:
>
> - `locations` (from `@ContextConfiguration`)
> - `classes` (from `@ContextConfiguration`)
> - `contextInitializerClasses` (from `@ContextConfiguration`)
> - `contextCustomizers` (from `ContextCustomizerFactory`) – this includes `@DynamicPropertySource` methods as well as various features from Spring Boot’s testing support such as `@MockBean` and `@SpyBean`.
> - `contextLoader` (from `@ContextConfiguration`)
> - `parent` (from `@ContextHierarchy`)
> - `activeProfiles` (from `@ActiveProfiles`)
> - `propertySourceLocations` (from `@TestPropertySource`)
> - `propertySourceProperties` (from `@TestPropertySource`)
> - `resourceBasePath` (from `@WebAppConfiguration`)

In this case, due to the different runtime, there is a difference in the `contextCustomizers` and thus no cached context is available and a new one will be started.